# error code : 5007

Tags: flash

I followed this tut http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix/ when testing I got

> 5007: An ActionScript file must have
>   at least one externally visible
>   definition

WHEREAS I DO HAVE A PUBLIC CLASS

```
package {   
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {
        public function DocumentClass() {
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();
            addChild(tf);
            tf.text = "Hello World";            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saving it as DocumentClass.as? The Class name, Constructor and AS file all need to have exactly the same name.

Other than that, hmm. It's possible that you have another DocumentClass.as somewhere within the same source path of your .fla, and this one is formed incorrectly? Have you created multiple files in the course of your experimentation with this tutorial?

Comment: I opened the fla file again my documentclass was empty maybe it was i didn't save it. It's working finally.